# Which is more correct in the sense of performance

Tags: c#

I have one question..

Which has more effective performance? Or which take less time to execute and **Why**?

```
session["var"].ToString()
```

or

```
(string)session["var"]
```

Comment: what type is `session["var"]` ? Also I have never seen `(string)var` before, ever. Maybe I've just been missing it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ToString() is a method and (string) is casting (Explicit). IMO casting is always fast

> A cast operation between reference types does not change the run-time
>   type of the underlying object; it only changes the type of the value
>   that is being used as a reference to that object.
>   
>   Source: [Explicit Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

.ToString() can be called from any object. This method is inherited from object class and can be overloaded

.(string) is a cast, Its not a function call. It should be used when it is sure that the object is already in string, it will throw an exception when it can't convert to string including null

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the type of object this session var is, if you know it is a string, option 2 is best.

Comment: Thanks for your response.... but can you tell me why is the second option is best? Is it explicit conversion or implicit conversion?

Answer (score 0):

The latter performs better, simply casting the value to a different type. The former involves a method call and/or a new object creation.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 calls are performing very different actions (unless you knwow for sure that the value is string). So asking which one is faster is not completely correct.

There are arguments both ways which one will be faster since both operations require call to a function. The right approach is to prototype and measure.

Note that it is unlikley that accessing data from Session will be your main performance botleneck (especially in case of SQL or other out-of-process session state).

Answer (score 0):

ToString() raise exception when the object is null. So in the case of object.ToString(), if object is null, it raise NullReferenceException. Convert.ToString() return string.Empty in case of null object. (string) cast assign the object in case of null. So in case of

```
MyObject o = (string)NullObject;
```

But when you use o to access any property, it will raise NullReferenceException.

Convert.ToString internally uses value.ToString. Casting to a String is cheaper since that doesn't require an external function call, just internal type checking. It is at least twice as fast to cast Object to String than to call Object.toString()